# Overriding the template files using a plugin for all themes

Tags: plugin-development, templates, archives, custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy

I believe these are the common filters to use when overriding a template

1. template_include
2. single_template
3. page_template
4. archive_template

The works but it seem that they are theme depended. I am using a theme called `hello elementor` from WordPress it is calling `index.php` as a blog archive template. So i tried to override that with `archive_template` but it does not work. I tried `template_include` which works but it overrides other templates of single and page templates also.

is_archive() returns

[image]

If the theme had archive.php I belive `archive_template` would have worked. So what's the method I should go for to make it work with all themes?

Comment: "If the theme had archive.php I belive archive_template would have worked." False. Conditional tags like `is_archive()` have nothing to do with what templates are used.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks. What if the `archive.php` does not exist?